# How to skip a React component from server side packaging?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Within a react component, I am using a JS library which has dependency on browser environment. I am using it by specifying the source in script tag. But while packaging from webpack for server side, I get error from the component which is using the reference of that library because it won't find it from server side.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Also please let me know if I am not using it in the right way.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. The problem is in import, not in any part of code which does not work in NodeJS server. Just the import statement is causing to load a module which has reference like "navigator", "window" so its failing during webpack build. And I think there is no good way to do conditional import in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I do this I add an environment variable in webpack, and then in whatever functionality check to see if that environment variable exists. If it doesn't, you are in the browser. If it does you are on the server.

You can also do things like checking if the `window` is defined. Basically check somehow to see which environment you are in and use a conditional to execute the code or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on your code:

```
const Foo = () => <div>Hello</div> 
const Bar = () => <div>World</div>

...
render () {
  return (typeof document === 'undefined')
     ? <Foo />
     : <Bar />
}
....
```